# How to close a detail tag automatically as one of their siblings is opened?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

This code below closes all other detail tags open if one of them gets opened

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
 const details = [...document.querySelectorAll('details')];
 if (!details.some(f => f.contains(e.target))) {
     details.forEach(f => f.removeAttribute('open'));
 } else {
     details.forEach(f => !f.contains(e.target) ? f.removeAttribute('open') : '');
 }
});
```

That's fine but I want to modify it so it will only close detail tags next to each other (siblings)

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     const details = [...document.querySelectorAll('details')];
      details.some(f => {
       if(f.previousElementSibling && f.previousElementSibling.contains(e.target) || f.nextElementSibling && f.nextElementSibling.contains(e.target)) {
        details.forEach(f => f.removeAttribute('open'));
       } 
      }); 
    });
```

```html
<div id="siblings1">
<details>
<summary>Parent 1</summary>
<details><summary>Child 1</summary>opened</details>
<details><summary>Child 2</summary>opened</details>
<details><summary>Child 3</summary>opened</details>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Parent 2</summary>
<details><summary>Child 1</summary>opened</details>
<details><summary>Child 2</summary>opened</details>
<details><summary>Child 3</summary>opened</details>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Parent 3</summary>
<details><summary>Child 1</summary>opened</details>
<details><summary>Child 2</summary>opened</details>
<details><summary>Child 3</summary>opened</details>
</details>
</div>
```

but I don't have it down right quite yet (clicking on the child will close its parent which I don't intend).

Goal: you click parent 1 and then child 1, then you click child 2, that should close child 1. Then you click parent 2, which should close parent 1 but its child 2 should remain open.

What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it my be easier if you don't start at document.

```js
const details = document.querySelectorAll('details')

function close_slblings(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  for (let sib of this.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope > details'))
    if (sib != this)
      sib.removeAttribute('open')
      // optionally recursively close their children details
}

for (let el of details) {
  el.addEventListener('click',close_slblings)
}
```

```css
details{padding-left: 1em;}
```

```html
<details>
 <summary>Parent 1</summary>
 <details>
   <summary>Parent 1-1</summary>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-1</summary></details>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-2</summary></details>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-3</summary></details>
 </details>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>
<details>
 <summary>Parent 2</summary>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>
<details>
 <summary>Parent 3</summary>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>
```

Comment: sorry, for some reason is not working inside my full code. Is it possible to wrap your solution in `document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {` ?

Comment: @CainNuke sure, you invoke `close_slblings` on `e.target` (or it's parent detail)

Comment: can you post an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Here comes `document` version.

note: you need to find the correct target in this version.

```js
function close_slblings() {
  for (let sib of this.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope > details'))
    if (sib != this)
      sib.removeAttribute('open')
      // optionally recursively close their children details
}

document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  let target_detail=e.target
  while(target_detail && !(target_detail instanceof HTMLDetailsElement)){
    target_detail = target_detail.parentElement
  }
  if(target_detail)
    close_slblings.call(target_detail)
})
```

```css
details{padding-left: 1em;}
```

```html
<details>
 <summary>Parent 1</summary>
 <details>
   <summary>Parent 1-1</summary>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-1</summary></details>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-2</summary></details>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-3</summary></details>
 </details>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>
<details>
 <summary>Parent 2</summary>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>
<details>
 <summary>Parent 3</summary>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>

something to click on
```

Comment: This one works much better! Thank you!

Comment: just one last question please. Lets say that instead of all details on the document, I want only details within a div with an id that contains the word "siblings". I tried this but it didnt work: `for (let sib of this.parentElement.querySelectorAll('[id*="siblings"] details'))`

Comment: @CainNuke the selector is wrong, you need `details[id*="siblings"]` (no space and tag first)

Comment: but that would only select detail tags with an id that contains "siblings" in the name. Wont it? I want to select all detail tags inside divs like this: `<div id="siblings1">` `<div id="siblings2">`

Comment: @CainNuke I see, I think you mean siblings is on detail tag.

Comment: no, siblings is the id of the container DIV.

Comment: @CainNuke first let me make sure, `this` is a detail element in `for (let sib of this.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope > details'))` so you're not closing it's sibling details but sibling div's child detail?

Comment: I edited my question accordingly. Please check it out.

Comment: @CainNuke I see, well, the easy way is attach the listener only to those `div` instead of `document`, can you do it?

Comment: For some reason it wont work on my document. I tried like this:  `const details = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id*="siblings"] details')];
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{`

Comment: @CainNuke I mean, don't addEventListener to `document` but the `div`s

Comment: Thats what Im trying to do like this:  `const container = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id*="siblings"]')]; container.addEventListener('click',e=>{`

Comment: @CainNuke because array doesn't have `addEventListener` (you need a loop)

Comment: I keep getting this error: redeclaration of const details

Comment: @CainNuke I think it time to open a new question. as there appears to be no enough space in comments to explain what you have. (the is no `const details` in the previous one comment.) and anyway redeclare of const is better for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the details element in the same level instead of querying every node.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let closetParent = e.target.closest("details");
  let siblings = [];
  if (closetParent && closetParent.parentNode) {
siblings = Array.from(closetParent.parentNode.childNodes);
for (let i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
  let sibling = siblings[i];
  if (sibling.tagName === "DETAILS" && sibling !== closetParent) {
    sibling.removeAttribute("open");
  }
}
  }
});
```

```html
<details>
 <summary>Parent 1</summary>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>
<details>
 <summary>Parent 2</summary>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>
<details>
 <summary>Parent 3</summary>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 2</summary></details>
 <details><summary>Child 3</summary></details>
</details>
```

Comment: Seems like it generates some erros. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Re [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585877/how-to-close-a-detail-tag-automatically-as-one-of-their-siblings-is-opened/73586297?noredirect=1#comment129945624_73586297) : you can attach it to any element, but note:

- use `stopPropagation` (depends on your use case)
- stop checking target at `this` (only work on it's children)

```js
function close_slblings() {
  for (let sib of this.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope > details'))
    if (sib != this)
      sib.removeAttribute('open')
  // optionally recursively close their children details
}

let target_divs = document.querySelectorAll('.GROUP')
for (let el of target_divs) {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    let target_detail = e.target
    while (target_detail != this && !(target_detail instanceof HTMLDetailsElement)) {
      target_detail = target_detail.parentElement
    }
    if (target_detail)
      close_slblings.call(target_detail)
  })
}
```

```css
details {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class=GROUP>
<details>
 <summary>Parent 1</summary>
 <details>
   <summary>Parent 1-1</summary>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-1</summary></details>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-2</summary></details>
 </details>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
</details>
</div>

<details>
 <summary>No collapse 1</summary>
 <details>
   <summary>Parent 1-1</summary>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-1</summary></details>
   <details><summary>Child 1-1-2</summary></details>
 </details>
 <details><summary>Child 1</summary></details>
</details>
```